# How to display configurable product list with color swatches option in home page Magento?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

I have used rwd theme, that theme have default option for color swatches option. that option was displayed from category pages, but am unable to display configurable products with color swatches option in the home page.

My current [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYpym.png)

what i expected: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywFq5.png)

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Login to admin

Go to : **`System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches > General Settings`**

Do setting as following

1. Enabled : Yes
2. Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing : Color

Hope this make sense to you

Comment: thanks rohit, i have done this but i use below code in cms page->home page ->content:
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

configurable product list are visible, but that options are not diplayed.

Please suggest..

Comment: Check `list.html`. Is it contains configurable swatches code?

Comment: Yes Rohit, Please see below : 
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }

Please suggest